# How to install package version that was removed from backports?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-squeeze, package-management, openoffice

There is only one version of the `libreoffice` package in Debian Squeeze Backports:

```
apt-cache madison libreoffice
libreoffice | 1:3.5.4-7~bpo60+1 | http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

But I need to install the previous one (`1:3.4.6-2~bpo60+2`)
Is there a way to install it using packages (I don't want to install libreoffice manually as it has a lot dependencies).

Comment: What leads you to believe that there was a `3.4.6-2~bpo60+2`?  Had you installed it previously, or what?  If you had installed it previously, it would be useful to know exactly how you had installed it before.

Comment: I installed it before using backports. But now it disappeared and only 3.5 version is available. Our application depends on 3.4.x version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use snapshot.debian.org, search libreoffice there:

http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/libreoffice/

Answer (score 1):

### It doesn't look possible via backports

Try looking on the backports website ...

http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/

Or the main debian repo http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/editors/

It looks like that version is only available on a few platforms `[mipsel, powerpc, s390]`

Checking `apt` on a `squeeze` machine, its only showing 1 available variant

```
[/]$ apt-cache policy libreoffice
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.5.4-7~bpo60+1
  Version table:
     1:3.5.4-7~bpo60+1 0
        100 http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

Then even forcing the archived `lenny-backports`

Eg.

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main"
```

And forcing an update of an expired repo

```
apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Will give an empty result

```
[/]$ apt-cache policy libreoffice
N: Unable to locate package libreoffice
```

### Possible solutions

**Have you read** this article about installing it on Squeeze?

http://debian.stevenrosenberg.net/index.php/2011/06/24/installing-libreoffice-in-debian-squeeze-from-backports-without-a-hitch/

Comment: Thanks very much! But the possible solution from the blog just describes LibreOffice installation from backports step-by-step